Wildfly 22.0.1 failing to deploy WAR that uses @Stateless classes
I am getting a strange error on Wildfly where it is not deploying a WAR file.
My exact setup is per the below:
OS : Windows 10
JDK : Amazon Correto 17.0.11.9.1
WildFly : 22.0.1.Final
IntelliJ : IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Analyzing the Wildfly logs we are presented with the following error:
2024-04-19 10:50:38,612 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) Ignoring failure to handle interceptor annotations for com.mycompany.job.RunMyJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class java.lang.Thread with ClassLoader null
    at org.jboss.as.server@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@22.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@22.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@22.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@22.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private volatile java.lang.String java.lang.Thread.name accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @31664cec
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.server@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.server@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    ... 13 more

Steps taken to try and resolve so far are:

Delete the ".m2" folder with all the Maven repositories
Re-import the project into IntelliJ
Remove all versions of Java from the machine apart from the one Amazon Correto
Upgrade IntelliJ to latest version

Key Observations Seen:

This issue has only recently cropped up and it all used to work just fine
There is nothing wrong with the WAR file it's trying to deploy I can take the compiled WAR and deploy it to another PC (Linux in this scenario)
Try manually starting Wildfly outside IntelliJ still gives same error

Root Lines Of Code:
The class com.mycompany.job.RunMyJob is a Quartz scheduled task, but more importantly it has the
@Stateless annotation at the top of it, which in turn uses the following import
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
Now removing the @Stateless causes the problem to be resolved. But we need the class to be stateless.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Forgot to add. I also re-downloaded Wildfly from scratch again, just incase it had a rogue temporary file or something like that.

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private volatile java.lang.String java.lang.Thread.name accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @31664cec <-- looks like this is your issue. Did you try on Java 11 ?

@ehsavoie I tried but the code won't even compile under Java 11 it's written using Java 17

Did you try to add: -add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED in the java command line in standalone.sh ? as shown in https://www.wildfly.org/news/2022/04/14/WildFly261-Final-Released/

Yes that's fixed the issue!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!
Two questions still remains though
Firstly why all of a sudden should I need that JVM option? The project was running just fine for months
Secondly what is that option actually doing for me?

It is a Java option due to the new modules in java since Java 9, so I guess / think that you have updated your JVM. In Oraclz Java 11: Some tools and libraries use reflection to access parts of the JDK that are meant for internal use only. This illegal reflective access will be disabled in a future release of the JDK. Currently, it is permitted by default and a warning is issued. I guess this is no longer permitted by default on 17
